# SQL query that removes a row of data based on 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a common table expression query that returns this set of data:

```
Board_Name  Method          Source          TicketCount Percentage
IT Services NULL            NULL            73          0.7
IT Services Call            Call            6929        69.7
IT Services Call            CallByReception 4303        43.3
IT Services Call            CallBySupport   2626        37.9
IT Services Chat            Chat            8           0.1
IT Services EmailConnector  EmailConnector  2047        20.6
IT Services Internal        Internal        51          0.5
IT Services Portal          Portal          829         8.3
```

In a `SELECT` statement, I would like to return all of the rows in the above result  **EXCEPT**  the rows that has the Method value equal to 'Call' and the Source value equal to 'Call'.

So the result of the query will be this:

```
Board_Name      Method          Source          TicketCount Percentage
IT Services     NULL            NULL            73          0.7
IT Services     Call            CallByReception 4303        43.3
IT Services     Call            CallBySupport   2626        37.9
IT Services     Chat            Chat            8           0.1
IT Services     EmailConnector  EmailConnector  2047        20.6
IT Services     Internal        Internal        51          0.5
IT Services     Portal          Portal          829         8.3
```

`;WITH CTE
AS
(--select statement returns the above result
 --details are not important
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE --I need to include all of the rows except the row that has the Method and Source columns are equal to 'Call'`

How can I construct the `where` clause to not include the one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be ([Demo](http://rextester.com/VGJ55852))

```
 WHERE NOT 'Call' = ALL(SELECT ISNULL(Method,'') UNION SELECT ISNULL(Source,''))
```

Or along similar lines ([Demo](http://rextester.com/XTW38001))...

```
WHERE  'Call' <> ANY(SELECT ISNULL(MS,'') FROM (VALUES (Method),(Source)) V(MS))
```

Or - [Demo](http://rextester.com/FOTW78120)

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'Call' INTERSECT SELECT Method INTERSECT SELECT Source)
```

Comment: Yep.  The update worked.  I have never seen a construct like that.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND/OR` logic to achieve this

```
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
WHERE  ( Method <> 'Call' AND Source <> 'Call' )
   OR  ( ( Method = 'Call' OR Method IS NULL ) AND ( Source <> 'Call' OR Source IS NULL ) )
   OR  ( ( Source = 'Call' OR Source IS NULL ) AND ( Method <> 'Call' OR Method IS NULL ) )
```

---

**DEMO**

**Schema & Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE cte
    ([Board_Name] varchar(25), [Method] varchar(15), [Source] varchar(15), [TicketCount] int, [Percentage] numeric(22,6))
;

INSERT INTO cte
    ([Board_Name], [Method], [Source], [TicketCount], [Percentage])
VALUES
    ('IT Services',NULL, NULL, 73, 0.7),
    ('IT Services','Call', 'Call', 6929, 69.7),
    ('IT Services','Call', 'CallByReception', 4303, 43.3),
    ('IT Services','Call', 'CallBySupport', 2626, 37.9),
    ('IT Services','Chat', 'Chat', 8, 0.1),
    ('IT Services','EmailConnector', 'EmailConnector', 2047, 20.6),
    ('IT Services','Internal', 'Internal', 51, 0.5),
    ('IT Services','Portal', 'Portal', 829, 8.3)
```

**Result :**

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| Board_Name  |     Method     |     Source      | TicketCount | Percentage |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| IT Services | NULL           | NULL            |          73 | 0.700000   |
| IT Services | Call           | CallByReception |        4303 | 43.300000  |
| IT Services | Call           | CallBySupport   |        2626 | 37.900000  |
| IT Services | Chat           | Chat            |           8 | 0.100000   |
| IT Services | EmailConnector | EmailConnector  |        2047 | 20.600000  |
| IT Services | Internal       | Internal        |          51 | 0.500000   |
| IT Services | Portal         | Portal          |         829 | 8.300000   |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: does not work.  You get only the rows that are 'email', 'portal', 'internal' in the Method column.  You don't get the 'call' or null Method rows

Comment: @GloriaSantin - check now

Comment: @GloriaSantin - check the latest one

Comment: Returned all of the rows.  Did not remove the one that I wanted.

Comment: @GloriaSantin - Added demo check now